# How to search for "x" or "any number" in a string?

Tags: javascript

I ran into a bit of a block when wanting to make a dice rolling script.

The idea is that you can input any amount of arguments to roll any amount of dice, `2d6 + 1d4 + 5d2 - [...]`.

How can I make a script that finds all the `x`d`y`'s and puts them into an array? It must be based on `x`d`y` instead of, for example, spaces for cases like `1d4+1d6-1d8`.

Comment: regex is your friend.

Comment: Don't you also need to include the sign (plus or minus) associated with each xdy in order to use the array correctly?

Comment: What does the minus mean in the final example? Actually what do the numbers x and y mean?

Comment: @ASDFGerte They are, but how do I make regex find *any* digit, then letter, then *any* digit?

@KyleDelaney Yes, any arithmetic operators actually, but it should also work with just a single `x`d`y` argument.

Comment: What do you mean with a variable? Can it be a comma, can it be "yes", or only digits, or with a sign or not? Can you please be precise?

Comment: Maybe some regex like `(\+|-){0,1}\s*(\d+)d(\d+)` would work, just loop through all matches and extract the groups: https://regex101.com/r/z4FKhU/1

Comment: @trincot x and y are simply undefined numbers ranging from - infinity to + infinity

Comment: Are they always integers, or can they have a decimal point?

Comment: By reading a tutorial about regex. This should be somewhere along the first few examples.

Comment: @trincot Unless there is a die with a number of sides with a decimal point, No.

Comment: But there can be dice with -Infinity sides?

Comment: @trincot ... Good point. 
What I meant originally is:
x is a number, no decimal points, that gives the calculator the amount of dice it has to roll. 
y is a number, no decimal points, that gives the calculator the amount of sides the dice has

Due to x being first, it can also be negative, like in case you want to subtract a result of a Y-sided die.

Negative sided dice is beyond my range of comprehension.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the pairs of numbers with [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll), like this:

```js
let s = "1d4+1d6-1d8";
let x = Array.from(s.matchAll(/(-?\d+)d(\d+)/g));
console.log(x);
```

This gives you an array of triplets. Each triplet has the xdy pattern that was matched, the value of x and the value of y (as strings).

If you need the x and y values as *numbers* instead of strings, then add a mapper callback to the `Array.from` call:

```js
let s = "1d4+1d6-1d8";
let x = Array.from(s.matchAll(/(-?\d+)d(\d+)/g), ([s, x, y]) => [+x, +y]);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Tested, exactly what I needed, and the latter version makes it even better.
Thank you! Surprised how fast I got the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Start with creating a function that takes a string (like "2d6") and returns a number

```
function rollDice(dicePattern) {
  var num = ... //use regex or indexOf ("d");
  var sides = ... //regex or substring(indexOf("d) + 1);
  var sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <num;i++) {
    //generate a random, multiply by sides, get the int value, and add it to sum
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Then split the string and call this on all your dice roll patterns

Comment: `Then split the string...` Isn't that what OP is asking how to do?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, regex is your friend. And regexr is super handy! https://regexr.com/4mvj6

`\d` will match a digit character, so `\dd\d` will match any number + 'd' + number combinations in your string.

```
// '2d6 + 1d4 + 5d2' => ['2d6', '1d4', '5d2']
function parseRolls(rollsString)
{
  if (rollsString)
  {
    return rollsString.match(/\dd\d/g);
  }
  return [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what the exact format you're expecting is, but this returns an array of objects with properties `x` and `y` given a string of `x`d`y`s delimited by plusses or minuses.

```js
function parseDiceRoll(rollString) {
  let rollBlocks = rollString.split(/[\+\-]/);
  return rollBlocks.map(roll => {
    let [x, y] = roll.split("d");
    return {x, y};
  });
}

console.log(parseDiceRoll("3d6+4d8-2d12"));
```